# Is there any API to get quickbooks reports list?

Tags: java, quickbooks-online

I have QuickBooks integrated with my Java application, I want to show list of reports of my QuickBooks account. For this I need a list of QuickBooks reports, is there any way to get all QuickBooks reports?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked if [these documented in QuickBooks API Reference](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/report-entities/accountlistdetail) is what you need?

Example of query to `JournalReport`:

```
GET /v3/company/<realmID>/reports/JournalReport?<name>=<value>[&...]

Accept type:application/json
Production Base URL:https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com
Sandbox Base URL:https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com
```

and sample query:

```
<BaseURL>/v3/company/<realmId>/reports/JournalReport
```